# Type to store time in C# and corresponding type in PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, time

I would like to know how to store time in **C#** and **PostgreSQL**

Ex:

```
var startTime = 8.00;
var endTime = 9.20;
var total = endTime - startTime ;
toatl is 80min
```

And then store this value in a database.

Comment: How do you save that value in database? 80, 01:20, ...

Comment: @doctore I do not save "toatl" in the database, it is only on the client side

Comment: The question was if you were going to store the number of minutes or going to convert it into a `HH:MM:SS` format, in this case the type that you need is TIME as @RoyDictus mentioned you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# you can use `DateTime` and in PostgreSQL you can use the `TIMESTAMP` type.

**EDIT**

If you only need to store time, and not date, then you can use the `TIME` type.
See also http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/datatype-datetime.html.

Comment: I do not need date, only time (hours)

Comment: In that case you can use PostgreSQL's `TIME` type. You can specify time zone or leave it out.